# Attempting to create a dashbaord based on the response sheet to a google form, this is

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Attempting to create a dashboard based on the response sheet to a google form, this is what I have based on a tutorial I viewed.. I have 70 + columns that I am trying to show as pie charts, should I be using a different method to pull that information?  I know there may be more than one error, but this is the one I am trying to figure out currently:

Object type does not match column type. (line 160, file "Code", project "History Department Dashboard")

```
function doGet() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MjS2zr9cQVvkn7qi1CmRucVT5IacDFijHR_dRSjthnY')
      var data = ss.getDataRange();

      var nameFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(4).build();

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([5]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([6]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([7]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([8]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([9]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([10]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([11]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([12]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([15]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([16]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([17]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([18]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([23]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([24]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([26]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([27]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([32]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([33]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([34]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([35]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([36]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([42]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([43]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([44]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([45]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([46]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([47]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([48]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([49]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([50]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([51]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([52]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([53]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([54]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([55]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([59]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([60]))

       var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([61]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([62]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([63]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([68]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([69]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([70]))

       var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([71]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([72]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([76]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([77]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([78]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([79]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([80]))

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([81]))

      var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
      .bind([nameFilter], [pieChart])
      .build()

      var app = UiApp.createApplication();
      var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
      var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
      filterPanel.add(nameFilter).setSpacing(10);
      chartPanel.add(pieChart).setSpacing(10);

      dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
      app.add(dashboard);
      return app;

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a chart for each column? every time you call var pieChart you are assigning the most recent value so at the end that variable will only have the value of Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([81]))

Comment: I was at first, but now I think that I would rather create one chart, and a control filter for each column so that the chart would change based on the parameters of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a Panel, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/dashboard-panel) you can find an example of how to do it and the necessary elements. You already have most of the required objects.

In the following code, I modified the example to make it similar to what you have and possibly to what you want.

After getting the complete range of information, you may only need a couple of columns to build a chart. When creating the chart you were using the function `setDataViewDefinition()`, as parameter then you added the fucntion `Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1])`. In this function you will select the columns from the data range that you will use for the chart. In this case I used the first and the second column `[0,1]`.
If you need the first and the third column, you would use `[0,2]`, and so on.

I also added a simple chart (without filters) in the variable `bars`. For that chart, I also defined the columns I needed and I just added it directly to the UI object.

If you are going to create that large amount of charts, I would suggest to use a for loop so you don't end up with a huge script.

Hope this helps.

```
function doGet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MjS2zr9cQVvkn7qi1CmRucVT5IacDFijHR_dRSjthnY');
   var data = ss.getDataRange().getDataTable();

   var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
       .setTitle("Ages").setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1]))
       .build();

   var stringFilter = Charts.newStringFilter()
       .setFilterColumnIndex(0)
       .build();

   var numberRangeFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter()
       .setFilterColumnIndex(1)
       .build();

   var bars =  Charts.newBarChart().setTitle('bar chart')
   .setDataTable(data)
   .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,2]))
   .build();

   // Create a dashboard panel binding both controls to the chart.
   var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
       .setDataTable(data)
       .bind([stringFilter, numberRangeFilter], [chart])
       .build();

   var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Dashboard");

   var panel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel().setSpacing(50);

   panel.add(stringFilter);
   panel.add(numberRangeFilter);
   panel.add(chart);
   dashboard.add(panel);
   uiApp.add(dashboard);
   uiApp.add(bars);
   return uiApp;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot!